# How to show a lot of images without setting visibility in AS3?

Tags: arrays, image, actionscript-3, visibility

I have made a quiz game and I want to be able to show an image right after a user answered correctly. The problem is i have a bunch of questions and images that it becomes tedious to set visibility for each and every image. How do I optimize this procedure. I was thinking of maybe placing the images in an array but i don't really know if its possible or to make it show up in the place that i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, the problem is that you have N images and you iterate each time over the whole set to set the visibility. In your case I would (as you suggested) create an array of those images and few helper functions. Some basic example:

```
private var imageVector: Vector.<DisplayObject>; // this vector holds all your images
private var currentImage: DisplayObject; // the image that is shown currently

private function createAndFillImages():void {
    imageVector = new Vector.<DisplayObject>();
    imageVector.push(image1); 
    imageVector.push(image2);
    //... etc. it depends on how your images are presented. 
}

private function onAnswerGiven():void {
    const img: DisplayObject = ... // pick the right image here 
    showImage(img)
}

private function showImage(img: DisplayObject):void {
    if (currentImage != null) currentImage.visible = false;
    currentImage = img;
    // ... do the positioning here 
    currentImage.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: how do you add images to imageVector?

Comment: @maggotypeach I've updated the answer, pls take a look. Hope it became more clear. In general it depends on your application and how the images are created, so there is no single "right" way.

Comment: i'm sorry for the newbie question but how to you actually call an image? Do you need to put the url of the image? or do you make a var image: new Image() ? if so how exactly do you do that?

Comment: @maggotypeach I assumed that you already have your images: `The problem is i have a bunch of questions and images that it becomes tedious to set visibility for each and every image.`